# How to SELECT a PROCEDURE in Firebird 2.5

Tags: select, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using Firebird Embedded v2.5. How to use procedures in query (SELECT) ?

My procedure:

```sql
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE PROCEDURE FN_TEST( Y INTEGER )
RETURNS( X INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
X = Y + 1;
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

I want to list some field of table modified by some procedure, like this:

```sql
SELECT some_table_field_1, 
       fn_test( 4 ) AS zzz, 
       some_table_field_2,
       fn_test( some_table_field_2 ) AS field_2_modified
FROM   tb_test
```

Need results (table):

```
some_table_field_1     zzz         some_table_field_2      field_2_modified
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
aaa                    5           14                      15
bbb                    5           23                      24
www                    5           75                      76
```

This thing works fine in PostgreSQL, but I don't know how to do this in Firebird.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you get an error message? If yes, post it

Answer (score 6):

```sql
SELECT some_table_field_1, 
   (select X from fn_test( 4 )) AS zzz, 
   some_table_field_2,
   (select X from fn_test( some_table_field_2 )) AS field_2_modified
FROM   tb_test
```

Comment: `fn_test` is not selectable (it's an [executable procedure](https://ib-aid.com/download/docs/firebird-language-reference-2.5/fblangref25-psql-storedprocs.html)). The proposed solution produces an _invalid request BLR at offset..._ error.

Comment: Add a SUSPEND; statement just before the END^ statement and the function becomes selectable.

Answer (score 4):

`FN_TEST` is an **executable procedure**: it can be called via the `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` statement and it returns a single set of output parameters.

In Firebird 2.x only a **selectable stored procedure** can be "used" as a view / table (see [Firebird Stored Procedures](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-psql-storedprocs.html)).

So:

```
SELECT FN_TEST(some_table_field) AS field_modified
FROM   tb_test
```

produces an *invalid request BLR at offset...* error.

You could change your procedure as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9370983/3235496) but, actually, the feature you need has been introduced in Firebird 3 in the form of [stored function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-psql-funcs):

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_TEST(Y INT) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN Y + 1;
END;

SELECT FN_TEST(4) AS zzz
FROM   tb_test
```

Further details in [Functions with PSQL in Firebird 3](https://www.ibphoenix.com/articles/art-00000395).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```sql
SELECT some_table_field_1, 
   fn_test.x AS zzz, 
   some_table_field_2,
FROM   tb_test
LEFT JOIN fn_test(some_table_field_1) ON (1 = 1)
```

Comment: `fn_test` is not selectable (it's an [executable procedure](https://ib-aid.com/download/docs/firebird-language-reference-2.5/fblangref25-psql-storedprocs.html)). The proposed solution produces an _invalid request BLR at offset..._ error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call stored procedures in Firebird's select list. You have to write the selectable procedure with desire result or write an UDF function to do what you have in `fn_test` procedure.

For your case the simplest way is:

```sql
SELECT some_table_field_1, 
       5 AS zzz, 
       some_table_field_2,
       ( some_table_field_2 + 1) AS field_2_modified
FROM   tb_test
```

Answer (score 1):

As [JustMe said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5258499/466862), you can't call stored procedures in a select. You can call stored procedure only in the FROM section. Another solution for your problem is to create a selectable procedure like this:

```sql
create or alter procedure myproc (
 n integer)
returns (
 field_1 integer,
 zzz integer,
 field_2 integer,
 modified_field_2 integer)
as
declare variable i integer;
begin
  for
    select some_table_field_1, :n+1 as zzz, some_table_field_2, (some_table_field_2+1) as field_2_modified
    from tb_test
    into :field_1, :zzz, :field_2, :modified_field_2
  do begin
    suspend;
  end
end
```

After run that code, you can simply query `select * from myproc(4)` and get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use UDF in order to manage calculation on fields.
Stored procedure are admited only in the FROM Clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```sql
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE PROCEDURE FN_TEST( Y INTEGER )
RETURNS( X INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
X = Y + 1;
SUSPEND;
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXECUTE BLOCK Please have a  look [EXECUTE BLOCK](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-execblock.html)