# SQL multiples select and group by using "first 1"

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group, firebird1.5

Despite the confusing title, I think it's pretty simple
I have a database in the following format:
(EXAMPLE)

```
---------------------------------
| X101| X102      | X103 | X104 |
---------------------------------
| COD | PROD_NAME | TYPE | INFO | 

| 05  | PROD A1   | 05   | ABC  |
| 019 | TAPE 01   | 05   | ABC  |
| 052 | MASTER 0  | 03   | ABC  |
| 111 | APPLE     | 03   | ABC  |
| 150 | RANDOM0   | 05   | ABC  |
| 235 | ITEM661   | 03   | ABC  |
| 290 | ITEM874   | 03   | ABC  |
---------------------------------
```

I've tried in many ways, but I have not come up with a result. The database has a little more than 20 thousand products, I wanted to know how to 
'select first 1' of each TYPE('group by TYPE' and show only the 'first 1' of each type)

Database is Firebird 1.5.

Comment: What columns defines the ordering for each type?

Comment: Which version of Firebird are you using?

Comment: Firebird 1.5 @MarkRotteveel

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Column 'Type', display only the first result with 05 and only the first result with 03, for example

Comment: Why are you still using Firebird 1.5?! The last release of 1.5 was 8 years ago, and since that time time a number of security bugs have been discovered and fixed, and a lot of new features have been added in recent versions that make it a lot easier to solve this in Firebird 3, than in Firebird 1.5.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am already providing migration to fb3.0, which has a lot more features and is much more secure, but for now, unfortunately, it must be 1.5

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group?rq=1 fixes your problem.

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem, then please do not edit your question to add things like "solved" to the title and a solution to your question, instead post an **answer** with your solution, and - after the timeout - **accept** it. I have rolled back your last edit.

Comment: that was not even a solution, work-around at best. The question was about Firebird, not about C# WPF

Answer (score 0):

First one by what order, specifically?

```
WITH TYPES AS
(
  SELECT TYPE, COUNT(*) AS 'COUNT' FROM EXAMPLE GROUP BY TYPE
)
SELECT
  TYPE,
  (SELECT TOP 1 PROD_NAME FROM EXAMPLE e WHERE e.TYPE = t.TYPE ORDER BY COD ASC) AS 'FIRST', 
  COUNT
FROM TYPES t
```

This results in the following:

```
TYPE | FIRST    | COUNT
-----|----------|------
03   | MASTER 0 | 4
05   | TAPE 01  | 3
```

This what you're after?

Comment: Exactly this result I need !!! But it did not work out here, 'TOP 1' does not recognize, maybe not for Firebird 1.5?

Comment: @ZaaPy Firebird doesn't have `top`, the equivalent is [`first`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-select.html#langrefupd25-first-skip), unfortunately CTE (common table expressions, ie `WITH`), was introduced in Firebird 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

One might use stored procedures.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectFirstOfTypes() 
         RETURNS (COD INT, PROD_NAME VARCHAR(15), TYPE INT, INFO VARCHAR(15)) AS 
BEGIN 
  FOR SELECT DISTINCT TYPE FROM EXAMPLE INTO :TYPE DO BEGIN
    FOR SELECT FIRST 1 e.COD, e.PROD_NAME, e.INFO FROM EXAMPLE e
    WHERE :TYPE = e.TYPE  INTO :COD, :PROD_NAME, :INFO DO BEGIN
       SUSPEND; 
    END
  END 
END;

GRANT SELECT ON EXAMPLE TO SelectFirstOfTypes;

SELECT * FROM SelectFirstOfTypes();
```

Note, that both `SELECT` statements are wrapped in FOR-loop.

- outer one - because it can return multiple rows,
- inner one - because it can return zero rows for specific types

Some links

- http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.WritingStoredProceduresAndTriggers
- http://www.destructor.de/firebird/storedproc.htm
- [How to SELECT a PROCEDURE in Firebird 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178085/how-to-select-a-procedure-in-firebird-2-5)
- http://www.pp4s.co.uk/main/tu-db-firebird-demo4.html

Answer (score -2):

If You don't have any condition for "first 1" you can simply try.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable GROUP BY TYPE
```

Comment: I've tried, but returns error:
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).

Comment: This might work in MySQL, it doesn't work like that in most other database systems, including Firebird.